# Desktop Action in .desktop file for Gnome not appearing

Tags: gnome, launcher

I am trying to set up some custom actions for a new `.desktop` file that I've created. Essentially I'm trying to create a "jump menu" of applications.

Here is some of the code I have:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Test
Icon=/home/luke/Pictures/icon.png
Exec=/home/luke/bin/test.sh
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;
Actions=ActionTest;

[Desktop Action ActionTest]
Name=Action Test
Exec=/home/luke/bin/test-action.sh
```

I have come to this code by looking at examples of other `.desktop` files, and also doing some Googling, but mostly from examples.

My launcher appears perfectly fine in the menu, and the bash script will execute.

I'm expecting that when I right click on the application launcher icon, I will see "Action Test" available as a menu option, however that isn't happening..

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you had this problem but with right-click on app launcher icon in Dash Dock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: `gnome-open app.desktop`
If that doesn't work, try `chmod +x app.desktop`

Comment: Thank you! I ended up both `gnome-open app.desktop` and `chmod`. There is a slight delay in the options being available in the launcher - I'm not sure if that's because I have to run `gnome-open` after making changes, or if it just takes a second for the system to read the file, but in any event, I'm getting things working now :)

Comment: Does this also solve Dash Dock right click missing Actions issue?